# MVC- Kendo DateTimePicker Culture Doesn't work with KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui

i am trying to change Kendo DateTimePicker's language.Added culture files to  change DatePicker on Page load.It works great if i dont apply knockoutjs binding.But i must use knockout's data-bind to make it works.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
     .Name("dtStart")
     .Culture(@CultureHelper.GetCultureShort())
     .Format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
     .TimeFormat("HH:mm")
     .ParseFormats(new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" })
     .Events(e => e.Change("dtStart_onChange"))
     //It stops changing to culture if i use "data-bind" here 
    //.HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "kendoDateTimePicker: selectedStartDate" })
               )
```

Tried this , but script works before datepicker created;

Js:

```
         var lang = '@CultureHelper.GetCultureShort()';
        $("#dtStart").kendoDatePicker({
        culture: lang,
            //....
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use that js to initialize the DateTimePicker. Since you're invoking it in Razor you can just call it up in your js and 'setOptions' with ::

```
$("#dtStart").data("kendoDatePicker").setOptions({
    culture: lang
}
```

Comment: Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setOptions' of undefined

Comment: Ah,it is "KendoDateTimePicker" not "KendoDatePicker".My mistake....
Thanks for answer.Now it works.

Comment: I think there is a bug with Kendo MVC DateTimePicker.Culture() property is not working when using  data-bind inside HtmlAttributes().

Comment: eh...DatePicker => DateTimePicker...js should have known what I meant ;)